# Trying to hide again line with code of string in Android Studio

Tags: android

my question is hard to explain in text, but easy in screenshot :)
When i click on lane, which value in string.xml Android Studio show to user what is there. Something like this:

[image: Screenshot]

My question is: how to hide again this text in Anrdoid Studio ?

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is called `Folding` and is by default set to shortcuts:

for expanding use  `ctrl+"+"`
for collapsing use `ctrl+"-"`

you can change these shortcuts in `File -> Settings -> Keymap -> folding`

this can also be done with the arrows on the side.

Hope this was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

`ctrl+"+"` to expand and `ctrl+"-"` to preview

Answer (score 0):

`Command+` to expand and `Command-` to collapse for anyone who uses a Mac.

Full list of commands for Windows/Linux and Mac [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/keyboard-shortcuts.html).